# Which one is most performant? "get" or "final"?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some localization files which have over 200+ Strings used inside a flutter app.That number is growing exponentially. So to tackle memory consumption i create the localizations dynamically so only one localization is built at any time.

Now. I declare the strings as

```
class ExampleLocalizations{
final String myFirstString = "myString";
final String mySecondString = "myString";
final String myThirdString = "myString";
//200 more
}
```

But i'm concerned that with time it's gonna be a problem having all those strings at once. So i'm questioning changing it to

```
class ExampleLocalizations{
  String get myFirstString => "myString";
  String get mySecondString => "myString";
  String get myThirsString => "myString";
}
```

Would this be the recommended solution? I think that dart will build the strings and when i remove the screen from navigation i wonder if the garbage collection will collect that unused string.

This can be applied to any type, the question is if it's more performant.

Comment: in the short answer  it will be more performant , 
i recommend to use https://pub.dev/packages/intl_utils/ 
the situation here is that you have to create the files as final String myFirstString = "myString"; and it will be generated as  String get myFirstString  {
    return Intl.message(
      'myString',
      name: 'myFirstString  ',
      desc: '',
      args: [],
    );
  }
so it ensure that it will be generated only when you call the String as a function not get all strings as value of class or what ever

Comment: Is `const` not an option?

Comment: Oh thank you. Unfortunately i have a custom localization implementation with theming and styling support to avoid code generation and adding more dependencies. So the feedback is really nice since it's the behaviour i expected. And no, const is not an potion since it's only for static variables and that would load everything at once. That's a big no no

Comment: @ValdaXD firstly you can apply any theme that you define to any flutter element without affecting the real string variable design , so what will you do when you have multiple languages?
i ensure you that if you used this package it will get the strings as global app functions and load only needed Strings ,the code generation here is better thant creating the Strings and support more functionalty if you want to pass arguments to the strings, if you need a complete example i can post you a complete example as an answer

Comment: @ChristopherMoore in this situation the const and final have the same effect

Comment: I wouldn't expect any difference.  `final` members implicitly declare `get`ters.  In general, if one way is strictly better than another way, and if the transformation between them is trivial, you usually should be able to assume that the compiler will make the optimization for you.